# How to animate the icon of a jQuery Mobile collapsible heading?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

Trying to use the standard icons of a jQuery Mobile to get a nice rotation animation when the collapsible is collapsed or expanded, but i'm getting a strange result, the whole collapsible title in the heading is rotated.

In my ideal solution, i would like to simply use the predefined jQM icon classes, without need to add an extra additional style just for that purpose.

Example: `icon-carat-u` and `icon-carat-d` are rotating by 180 degrees so they are animating when the collapsible is expanding and collapsing, respectively.

Moreover, i try avoid to use the `click` event, because the collapsible icon should be animate also when i am using in code `collapsible("expand")` or `collapsible("collapse")`.

Here is my code:

```css
.ui-icon-carat-d {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
     transition: .3s;
}
.ui-icon-carat-u {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can i rotate the standard *carat* icons to get a nice smooth animation in a jQuery Mobile collapsible heading?

Answer (score 3):

First thing's first - the reason the entire bar is spinning in your code rather than just the caret, is that `.ui-icon-carat-d` and `.ui-icon-carat-u` are classes on the bar itself. The caret icon is in an [`::after` pseudo-class](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/#article-header-id-6) of that bar.

With that said, I'm going to preface this by saying that this is not a beautiful solution, but it is a solution nonetheless.

To understand why this can't be more simple, you have to realize what's happening in jQuery Mobile's stylesheet for this caret. Essentially, the caret AND the upside-down caret are separate, unrelated SVG icons that are being swapped out as CSS-encoded background-images.

Because of this, that change cannot be animated as-is - the browser doesn't know anything about those images, and it certainly can't do a clever animation between them.

**So**, my solution begins by copying/pasting the SVG background-image that represents the "regular" caret from jQuery Mobile's styles, and forcing it to show also for the upside-down state, so that we can animate it in a traditional way.

As such, I'm targeting the element with the caret icon (an `::after` pseudo-class), applying the regular caret SVG `background-image` to it, and forcing it to hold on that image for both states of the toggle (with an `!important`).

Then, when jQuery Mobile adds the `.ui-icon-carat-u` class (upside-down), the image no longer changes, and we simply rotate the icon 180 degrees with a `transform`, and animate that with a `transition`.

Hope this helps! Test it below.

```css
.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20points%3D%2211.949%2C3.404%207%2C8.354%202.05%2C3.404%20-0.071%2C5.525%207%2C12.596%2014.07%2C5.525%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") !important;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.ui-icon-carat-u::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using actually this CSS .`ui-icon-carat-d::after {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: .5s;
}
.ui-icon-carat-u::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: .5s;
}` and it is spinning nicely, but because i'm a newbe in CSS transformations and transitions, i can't yet understand why it isn't possible to make just only a half circle rotation. I believe i need to deepen this topic to fully understand your sentence "the browser certainly can't do a clever animation between two separated unrelated icons". My fault. Any suggestion about that?

Comment: @deblocker I've adjusted my code to do a half-circle rotation, per your comment. The reason it's not possible to do so with the default jQuery Mobile styles is that the caret is NOT rotating via CSS - the icon is being replaced with a different image. There's unfortunately no way in CSS to transition between two background-images, so in my example I'm forcing the image to stay on the first, regular caret the whole time.